# JHipster Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain

Tags: java, jhipster

I created two JHipster projects, the same way, a gateway and a microservice. The microservice has nothing wrong, however whene I try to run `./mvnw clean install` in the gateway root I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain
```

The only way I found to fix this is to copy the `maven-wrapper.jar` from `.mvnw/wrapper` of the microservice app to the gateway. Of course I think there should be a better way to fix this. Any idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My guess is that you copied `mvnw` from somewhere else. That will not work because, as you mentioned, the dependencies of the script are not properly set up.

Run `mvn -N io.takari:maven:wrapper` at the root of your projects.

https://github.com/takari/takari-maven-plugin

Comment: Note that this command is not related to JHipster, it also works with Quarkus or Springboot.

Comment: "On my computer" it was sufficient to invoke the script from the project's root.